# Dynamically adding items to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm having trouble adding items to the array. I want to get the heights of `<p>` elements on the page and add them to the array. But every time it gets an array with one element, it looks like the previous value is resetting.

```
const Paragraph = () => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const [arrayWithHeight, setArrayWithHeight] = useState([]);

  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
    addItemsToArray(ref.current.clientHeight);
  }, [addItemsToArray]);



  function addItemsToArray(height) {
    setArrayWithHeight(heights => [...heights, height]);
  }

  console.log('arrayWithHeight', arrayWithHeight)

  return (
   <div>
      <p ref={ref}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
      <p ref={ref}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p ref={ref}>Lorem</p>
    </div>

  );
};
```

export default Paragraph;
Examples of output: [113], [124], [55]. However, I would like to receive one table [113,124,55]. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I don't understand how 2 paragraphs would give you three `console.logs`. In this case, you should just be using two separate refs for each paragraph. If you need to be more dynamic, you should look at https://dev.to/oussel/a-guide-for-refs-in-react-45l6#chapter-1

Comment: I update the code. In my realy code I have a lot of paragraphs.

Comment: [This code doesn't seem to run](https://codepen.io/jmendes/pen/XWzqvYO?editors=1111) Can you update that to reproduce your problem and respond with a link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-meadow-82ukpl?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arrayWithHeight` array is redeclared every render cycle and only a single value is pushed into it. Convert `arrayWithHeight` to local component state and use a functional state update to retain the previous state values.

React state updates are also asynchronously processed, so trying to use the `height` state to add to the `arrayWithHeight` state won't work since it won't have been updated yet. Use the current height ref value instead.

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
const [arrayWithHeight, setArrayWithHeight] = useState([]);

const ref = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
  addItemsToArray(ref.current.clientHeight);
}, [addItemsToArray]);



function addItemsToArray(height) {
  setArrayWithHeight(heights => [...heights, height]);
}
```

### Update

You've only a single ref, you'd need a ref for each paragraph to get each one's height. The following is a way to store an array of refs ***and*** get their computed heights. Spread the array of heights into the `Math.Max` function to return the maximum height value

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

const heightRefs = useRef([]);

heightRefs.current = data.map((_, i) => heightRefs.current[i] ?? createRef());

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setHeight(
    Math.max(
      ...heightRefs.current.map((el) =>
        Number(getComputedStyle(el.current).height.match(/\d+/).pop())
      )
    )
  );
}, []);
```

...

```
<div>
  {data.map((el, i) => (
    <p
      key={el}
      ref={heightRefs.current[i]}   // <-- ref by index
      style={{ minHeight: height }} // <-- set a minimum height
    >
      {el}
    </p>
  ))}
</div>
```

[image: Edit billowing-water-u0t9jx]

Comment: I get array  for each height
(9879) [113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, …]

Comment: @Elder Eh, yeah, looking at the code with more context it doesn't make a lot of sense. `addItemsToArray` is redeclared each render cycle, and will trigger the `useEffect` hook callback and likely create a render loop. What is this component rendering and what is the `ref` attached to? Can you post a more complete code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ***When*** do you *actually* want to set the `height` state and update the heights array?

Comment: I want to collect the height of all the paragraphs on the page and make them equal height.

Comment: @Elder You've only a single ref, you'd need a ref for each paragraph to get each one's height. Are you mapping these paragraphs from some other data? Are you wanting to grab the size of the biggest paragraph? The smallest?

Comment: I want to get the height of the tallest element. Yes, I mapping these paragraps with cms data,

Comment: @Elder Can you update your minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: @Elder See https://thewebdev.info/2021/02/04/how-to-assign-multiple-refs-for-an-array-of-elements-with-react-hooks .  It's unclear how you think this is going to iterate over each of the `<p>`s. I think your first step is to understand how to get a ref to multiple elements.

Comment: I think this link to the article is not correct, because it is about adding an html tag.

Comment: @Elder I've added to my answer handling an array of React refs. Please check it out.